# Meaning of 言葉は殴り返せない

Tags: meaning

In the below how is 言葉は殴り返せない meant to be understood. Is it similar to 言い返せない, or is there a meaning I am missing?

To provide some context, the character is talking to her friends 咲希 and 桃 about the problems she is having with her boyfriend.

「ビッチの正論なんて聞きたくないの」

「じゃあなんで咲希のこと呼んだの！？　帰っていい？」

「帰らないで！　桃ちゃんだけだともっと正論パンチが飛んできそうで怖いから。**言葉は殴り返せない**から。」

Comment: This is not a set phrase or a well-known saying. You have to make sense of this "words cannot punch back" purely using the context. For now I cannot even get who throws this 正論パンチ. What are they trying to do? What type of character is 桃ちゃん, and is the on the speaker's side?

Comment: added a bit more context. this person is talking to their two friends 咲希 and 桃 about problems she is having with her boyfriend and 咲希 responds with a fair comment leading to the above exchange.

Comment: I don't understand 桃ちゃんだけだともっと正論パンチが飛んできそう in this context yet. "You (咲希) are good at fast talk but 桃 is not, so if only 桃 and me confront my boyfriend, I expect 正論パンチ from my boyfriend" or "桃 is more critical than you, so I expect 正論パンチ from 桃 if you leave me now"?

Comment: It would be the latter.